# My hero academia season 3 ep 13

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

My hero academia season 3 ep 13 what is the ost when they going in dormitory? (First minutes)

Answer (score 0):

The OST is : **Watashi Kara Kimi e**
(Season 2 OST)

Here's a link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lr3G4zTyP50